# what is difference between t-test and 10-fold validation?

Tags: machine-learning, t-test, cross-validation

one of famous significant test is t-test which can conclude is our result by chance or not using previous results and their variance. Also when we use 10-fold validation we break our dataset to train and test chunks and learn&test iterativly over them. Then we can calculate our average and variance of our results.

what baffle me is that what is the exact difference between a significant test like t-test and 10-fold validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They serve completely different purposes. Cross-validation is used to estimate generalization performance, whereas (two sample) t-tests are used to assess the probability for two samples to originate from the same distribution.

The data partitioning in cross-validation is done to ensure that performance is always evaluated based on independent data, that is data that was not used for building the model. A t-test doesn't involve any data partitioning.

Both cross-validation and t-tests can be used for model selection, but not in a competing way. Typically, you would be combining both of them, that is acquire a sample of performance estimates via cross-validation and then use a t-test (or noninferiority test) to see whether one model significantly outperforms another. That said, a t-test is ill suited for such comparisons (though not uncommon), as the normality assumption underlying the test won't hold.